# WCF. How to add custom DataContact types to WCF Client reference?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services-client

I have a WCF service with method:

```
[OperationContract]
public bool TestCustomRequest(RequestBase request)
{
    return true;
}
```

In referenced Class Library project I have 2 classes:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class RequestBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public RequestTypeEnum RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

And inherited class:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomRequest : RequestBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

When on client side I'm adding service reference, I can see only `RequestBase` class. Is it possible, to add all classes that inherits `RequestBase` into service reference and initialize them on client side?

Or I have to overload `TestCustomRequest` method for each possible incoming parameter type ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CustomRequest))]
public abstract class RequestBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public RequestTypeEnum RequestType { get; set; }
}
```